# Bark on plum tree concern

Tags: trees, diagnosis, diseases, fruit-trees, tree-care

I noticed earlier on our plum tree that the bark on one of the limbs is a very slight reddish colour and what look like cracks.

You can see the another tree limb on the left that looks fine

[image]

[image]

Any ideas as to what this could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older .vs. younger bark. Nothing more.

Comment: Such a relief, thanks very much!